# Cannot install PyQt5

Tags: linux, installation, python, tar

I downloaded a package from this site [PyQt5_gpl-5.12.1.tar.gz](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)

But when installing...

```
[****@localhost PyQt5_gpl-5.12.1]$ python3.7 ./configure.py --qmake /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake-qt5


Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.12.1 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.7.2 on Linux.

Type 'L' to view the license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes

Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Error: Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument
to explicitly specify a working sip.
```

And then I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
[****@localhost PyQt5_gpl-5.12.1]$ python3.7 ./configure.py --qmake /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake-qt5 --sip /usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/sip.so
Error: '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/sip.so -V' did not generate
any output.
```

**I use Fedora Linux 29**